# Boundary terms in AdS space

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, variational-calculus, anti-de-sitter-spacetime, boundary-terms

Given the metric in AdS space
$$
ds^2=\frac{r^2}{L^2}(-dt^2+d\vec{x}^2)+\frac{L^2}{r^2}dr^2
$$

I am trying to calculate the variation of the action of the KG equation in this metric.

What would be the determinant of the induced boundary metric on the AdS space $\sqrt{-h}$?
Also what would be the normal vector field $n^r$?